# CSS Form Submit

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a site with the following PHP on it:

```
echo "<form action='choice.php' method='post'>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='choice' value='left' /> ";
```

I am using bootstrap and wondering how to apply the bootstrap style to these buttons? I would except to just add a  but im not sure how. Or would it be better to use a bootstrap button that replicates this functionality? If so how?

Comment: Does adding the `bootstrap` classes not work on the `input`?

Answer (score 1):

To use bootstrap button class, try this:

```
echo "<input type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' name='choice' value='left' /> ";
```

Comment: Yep, that should work now. 1+

Answer (score 0):

Go with andre3wap's answer if you want to keep using the `<input>` element. But for completeness sake, if you want to replace it with a `<button>` element:

Change:

```
echo "<input type='submit' name='choice' value='left' /> ";
```

to:

```
echo "<button class='btn btn-primary' type='submit' name='choice'>left</button>";
```

Twitter bootstrap does support more types of buttons, check: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons for all the button styles.

Answer (score 0):

You can EASILY do this by just adding the right attributes to the code:

```
echo '<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="choice">left</button>';
```

Notice I changed from input to button because it is more semantic, though if you you are developing for IE6 then go back to input.